# How does WCF base64 encode the public key in client app.config

Tags: wcf, x509certificate

I am just playing arround with WCF and certificates. I have installed a certificate on my computer, referenced it in my WCF service config like this:

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="testcert"
                    storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                    storeName="My"
                    x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
```

I then start the service. All is fine. Then I create a simple client console program in visual studio, by adding the service as a service reference. I can infact contact the service, so all is working correctly! When I look in my app.config for my client, I have this identity:

```
<identity>
<certificate encodedValue="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" /></identity>
```

I have read somewhere that this value, is the base64 encoded value of the public key, that is served by the wsdl of the service. Is this correct? If I look at the wsdl, the public key here is,

```
<Identity xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity">
   <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <X509Data>
         <X509Certificate>
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
         </X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
   </KeyInfo>
</Identity>
```

And it matches the public key, when I export the key (base64 encoded export) from the certificate store. All fine. But what I dont get how the value from the wsdl and export corresponds to value in the client app.config file? If I base64 encode the exported value (or the value from the wsdl), i dont get the encoded value.

So my questions is: how is the value, in the client app.config file encoded? Have I missed something? Is it even the public key that is present in the client app.config at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the values are for a certificate with the thumbprint B854C6D815071FC2529B5572C6B0A013368E41F0 and subject CN=testcert

One of them is the base64 encoding of the the bytes of what your would get if you used this method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxz81eb9(v=vs.110).aspx) and passed the Cert X509ContentType and the other is using the SerializedCert X509ContentType.

I don't know why one is used over the other but they represent the same thing (though from the link I posted, it appears the SerializedCert contains properties that were included in the Windows certificate store as well as the certificate itself)

Comment: So they represent a certificate with some information, among those a public key?

Comment: Yes, in your instance it has a 4096 bit RSA public key